# context.SaveChanges() wont work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I click a button in my form a new member is created.
This new member with properties is passed as a parameter to the database class 
UpdateMember method.

In the UpdateMember method there is a search for the member with the same id and then the member on that place is replaced with the member passed in the parameter.

Now the problem is that the list of members is now updated, but the context.SaveChanges doesn't agree with me (it doesn't update the database).

This is the code in the form:
db is an instance of the Db class

```
 private void updateMember()
    {
        Member mbr = new Member();
        mbr.membernr = int.Parse(nr.Text);
        mbr.firstname = fName.Text;
        mbr.lastname = lName.Text;
        mbr.birthdate = Convert.ToDateTime(bDay.Text);
        mbr.gender = gender.Text;
        mbr.paid = int.Parse(paid.Text);
        db.UpdateMember(mbr);
    }
```

This is the database class

```
class Db
{
    private SportDBEntities context;
    private static Db db;
    private List<Member> members;

    private Db() {
        context = new SportDBEntities();
    }

    public static Db GetInstance() {
        if (db == null) {
            db = new Db();
        }
        return db;
    }

    public List<Member> GetMembers() {
        members = new List<Member>();
        GetMembersFromDb();
        return members;
    }

    private void GetMembersFromDb() {
        var query = context.Members;
        foreach (Member m in query) {
            members.Add(m);
        }
    }

    public Member GetMemberAt(int index)
    {
        return members[index];
    }

    public void UpdateMember(Member mbr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < members.Count; i++)
        {
            if (members[i].membernr==mbr.membernr) {
                members[i] = mbr;
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe in method `GetMembersFromDb()`. You can set breakpoint to `query` and try again

Comment: Already tried that. If i log what context.SaveChanges does it returns 0. The zero means that there apparently no changes to be made.

Comment: That's likely because the context doesn't know the state of the object has changed - is possibly still set to `Unchanged`. Consider this line of code to let your context know the object has changed: `context.Entry(/* your object here */).State = EntityState.Modified;` You can read about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are not updating an instance from the context, instead you are completely replacing it by an unattached/transient object stored in mbr variable.

```
var existingMbr = members[i];
existingMbr.firstname = mbr.firstname;
existingMbr.lastname = mbr.lastname;
existingMbr.birthdate = mbr.birthdate ;
existingMbr.gender = mbr.gender;
existingMbr.paid = mbr.paid;
```

As *existingMbr* is being tracked the context should detect the changes

BTW you must be careful when you update sensitive data as *membernr*. It may have an important significance for your business.

Comment: This was indeed the problem, context couldn't track these changes. Thanks for helping me :)

BTW the membernr is not changeable, this field on the form is readonly for info purposes only.